# netsuite_client gem in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netsuite

I'm all new to rails stuff, and I'm trying to include netsuite_client gem into the rails application. So, I include the netsuite_client gem into the gem file and run bundle install, all goes well. I start the rails server, it starts normally, but when I try to access the app via browser, I get (trace)(note that this is freshly created app) :

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server<br />
[2011-11-21 13:18:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-21 13:18:25] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
[2011-11-21 13:18:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5236 port=3000
[2011-11-21 13:18:30] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/netsuite_client-0.0.2/lib/netsuite_client/string.rb:18:in `constantize'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:148:in `_default_wrap_model'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:167:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:120:in `wrap_parameters'
        C:/Sites/test_app/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:234:in `<class:Base>'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:171:in `<module:ActionController>'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:31:in `ext'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:15:in `match?'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:47:in `call'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:455:in `call'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any ideas where to go from here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`netsuite_client` hasn't been updated in years. The most up-to-date and fully functional implementation of the NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP API is the netsuite gem. You can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite) as well as on [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/netsuite).